# setting shortcut keys in different form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have one toolstrip if i click that tool strip ,that will ope two separate page,i given code in the tool strip like this:

```
    Dim frm As New frmKeyAssignBoard
      frm.Location = New Point(0, 0)
      frm.MdiParent = Me
      frm.Show()
    Dim frm1 As New FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
      frm1.Location = New Point(365, 0)
      frm1.MdiParent = Me
      frm1.Show()
```

actually this two forms are my child forms,,after opening this two forms i want to set shorcut key,i mean if i click K cursor should focus on particular text box in frmKeyAssignBoard,if i click R cursor should focus on particular text box in FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest.. 
How i can achieve this,i am using vb.net code

Answer (score 0):

Try this: override [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) method in your main form and handle the event.

You said you wanted shortcuts for  K and R keys, I assume you meant <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

```
Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case keyData
        Case (Keys.Control Or Keys.K)
            ' focus on particular text box in frmKeyAssignBoard
            Return True
        Case (Keys.Control Or Keys.R)
            ' focus on particular text box in FrmrecievedDelivaryRequest
            Return True
        Case Else

    End Select

    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)

End Function
```